# Including a comma at the end of a list before a dependent clause

Tags: commas

I have this sentence on my resume:

> Develop the front-end of a platform using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap to connect people and systems

Is there a comma after Bootstrap? I wanted to elaborate on the reason for building the application rather than simply listing the programming languages I used.

Comment: @Robusto: that question is about the Oxford comma, which in this case is after CSS, and is **not** the comma that the OP is asking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the platform uses HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap to connect people and systems, I can't see any advantage to introducing a pause before "using"—and you certainly wouldn't gain anything by putting a comma after "Bootstrap." That is, the minimally punctuated sentence

> Develop the front end of a platform using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap to connect people and systems.

conveys the intended meaning just fine.

On the other hand, if you developed the front end of a platform to connect people and systems, and you accomplished this by using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap, you might well want to use some sort of punctuation—paired commas, open and close parentheses, or paired em dashes—to break out the phrase "using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap," to indicate that the phrase constitutes an independent clause in the larger sentence. That is,

> Develop the front end of a platform, using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap, to connect people and systems.

or

> Develop the front end of a platform (using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap) to connect people and systems.

or

> Develop the front end of a platform—using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap—to connect people and systems.

would convey the intended meaning in this second scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Any of Sven Yarga's suggestions would work (note that in all cases "front end" is not hyphenated, because you are using it as a noun, not an adjective).

I would like to suggest one more altrnative. If you want to emphasize the reason for developing the front end, put the reason *at the front end of your sentence*:

- To connect people and systems, used . . .  to develop a front end .  . ."

(assuming these are the tools you used to develop the front end.)

And then you might list the tools at the back end:

- To connect people and systems,  develop(ed) a front end for a platform using .  . ."

(Unfortunately, this has a slight ambiguity as to whether you used those tools to build the front end, or whether they were used by others to build the platform, or both. However, it has the advantage of showing firstly the goal/purpose, then the action, and lastly the method.)

I realize this might mess with the parallelism of your "experience" bullet points. I don't know whether other bullet points in your résumé might be amenable to such a rearrangement.